# Generating random numbers in specific binary range

Tags: matlab, random, binary

I have a matrix with decimal numbers and I know I can convert them to binary using this code:(IEEE 754 double-precision binary)

```
m = reshape(dec2bin(typecast(b(:),'uint8'),8).',1,[]);
b_recovered = reshape(typecast(uint8(bin2dec(reshape(m,8,[]).')),'double'),size(b));
```

Using this code, I think 8 last bits are most significant bits. 
I want to generate random decimal numbers and replace these elements as 8 last bits won't change after replacing with generated random numbers. I need to have a new number while keeping 8 last bits.

For example:

```
b=-1.12;
m=1110110001010001101110000001111010000101111010111111000110111111;
```

be replaced by:

```
 m=0000110000000000001110000000011010000001100010000010000110111111;
```

Which is equal to:

```
b=-1.337678432804527e-04
```

I know that I can generate random decimal numbers between two numbers but I'm not sure how to solve the above mentioned problem.

```
mymatrix(1:q,:)= value2 + (value2-value1).*rand(q,size(y_blk,2));
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Converting a number from decimal to binary, changing the first 56 bits and then converting it back to a decimal?? It seems like there'd be a shortcut depending on what you expect as an end result...

Comment: Generate integers between 0 and 255 (8bits) and convert those to binary.

Comment: @mpaskov It's not that simple...8 last bits are not equal to 0-255

Comment: Misunderstood the question, you are keeping the last 8bits, and replacing the first 56, which are equal to 0-2^56. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Hanna is there something else that is missing from the answer?

Comment: @mpaskov I think the format of data is not considered in the answer. Please take a look at the question and answers here. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/327099-msb-after-converting-decimal-values-to-binary

Comment: @Hanna So what is your ultimate goal, to find which bit is the most significant? The question might need to rephrased. The most significant bit would be nr 57 as mentioned in the link. That is because, the conversion chops 64 bits into 8bit long integers, the last integer being the most significant and `bin2dec` uses the left most bit as the most significant. Which is the bit of the last 8 bit integer -> 57.

Comment: @mpaskov Finding MSB is not my question. As you have mentioned, I don't have just a decimal to binary conversion but to IEEE 754 double-precision binary. So, I want last 8 bits stay the same while other bits can be changed. And I want it to happen randomly. Like what we have in rand().

Comment: Well that is what the answer below does or is something missing?

Comment: Yes that's right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Keeping the first 56 replacing the last 8**

Generate an integer between `0` and `255` and convert it to binary. Replace the first/last 8 bits of you sequence with them.

```
b=-1.12;
m = reshape(dec2bin(typecast(b(:),'uint8'),8).',1,[]);
m_small = [dec2bin(randi(256)-1,8), m(9:end)]
m_large = [m(1:end-8),dec2bin(randi(256)-1,8)]
b_small = reshape(typecast(uint8(bin2dec(reshape(m_small,8,[]).')),'double'),size(b));
b_large = reshape(typecast(uint8(bin2dec(reshape(m_large,8,[]).')),'double'),size(b));
```

The value of `b_small`, hardly change indicating that the first 8bits are the least significant. `b_large` change is massive so the last 8 are the most significant bits.

---

**Keeping the last 8 replacing the first 56**

Misunderstood the question you want to keep the last 8 bits and replace the rest. In that case generate 56bits random data and add the last 8 that you have saved. Now as it turns out Matlab can only generate a max int of `2^53`. Instead of generating one integer up to `2^56`, generate 7 each one being `2^8`, and concatenate them.

```
m_new = [reshape(dec2bin(randi(2^8,[7,1])-1,8),[1,56]), m(end-7:end)]
b_new = reshape(typecast(uint8(bin2dec(reshape(m_new,8,[]).')),'double'),size(b));
```

Comment: Can I keep just bit 57 and 58?

Comment: Yes, you would save `m(end-7:end-5)` and add `dec2bin(randi(2^6)-1,6)` to the end.